# sqlcmd "unbuffered" output

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, unbuffered

How do I get *unbuffered* output when using `sqlcmd`

Lets say I have a file:

```
while (1=1)
begin
        print '------------------------------------------------------'
        select NOW=getdate(), DB=db_name()

        waitfor delay '00:00:01'
end
go
```

And I execute the above file with:

```
sqlcmd -Usa -S srvName -P passwd -i xxx.sql
```

I would expect ouput every second!
But it takes about a minute or two before anything is returned

So if I want to "report" anything in the SQL *batch* I can't tdo that???

**Is there anyway I can change this behaviour?**

**NOTE 1**: The OS I'll be using is Linux, but when testing, it was the same behaviour on both platforms
**NOTE 2**: I'm used to Sybase and `isql`, which is "unbuffered"

Comment: You can try adding some `raiserror with nowait` to flush the buffer but I know that was broken for a bit in `sqlcmd` - not sure if it was ever fixed

Comment: no changes with: `raiserror with nowait`